# Upon the change of babel default language, errors appear

Tags: overleaf

I used a template provided by my exchange university, where I learned to use LaTeX, changed the default language using babel package and where before I had 0 errors in the logs, now I have 7, without any clue how to fix them. By changing it back to the english as default language, it is solved. Though I should try to get it working with latvian package, as that is the language of my home university.

Could anyone perhaps take a look at this file and maybe can spot something I can't?
https://www.overleaf.com/read/vkppvyvymrgz

Thanks!

Comment: it's complaining about chapter commands but you have `\documetclass{article}` I didn't trace everythung but try `\documentclass{report}` instead. (please don't just llink to overleaf, try to make a self contained example to add here, your question is archived here forever and will not make sense if the overleaf link changes)

Comment: My bad on the post - I really wasn't sure what to post in here given the structure of the document ( having different folders etc )

On the main topic - it worked. It solved the error messages left. My question is - is there an essential difference between using class of report or article?

Comment: yes report and book class define `\chapter` but `article` class is for smaller documents and only has section levels from `\section` down and `\chapter` is not defined. all three are generated from the same source so that is by far the main difference, there are some other difference in default heading styles etc, but all minor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the code is configuring `\chapter` level style, assuming the main document class defines chapters but the example is using

```
\documentclass{article}
```

which only has `\section` and below.  Changing `article`  to `report` or `book` would enable `\chapter` formatting.

Comment: Is there a particular reason the code is trying to configure \chapter level style? Seems weird as the only thing I really changed, was the default language in the babel package

Comment: + as David suggested already, this solution worked!

Comment: no as I say I didn't read all of your code to see wht was setting up chapters, the change is almost certainly unrelated to babel @Richards

Comment: Alright, I'll just take the solution that works. Was just saying that nothing else apart from that was changed besides deleting unnecessary stuff.
Thanks again!

Comment: @Richards, `hyperref` looks for `c@chapter` when loaded after `[latvian]babel` and can't find it in `article` class; works OK if `hyperref` is loaded *before* `babel`. MWE: ```\documentclass[a4paper]{article}%report}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[latvian]{babel}
\begin{document}
\section{Virsraksts}
 Question 1
\end{document}```